# How is Gyro drift error related to error in velocity and position?

Tags: accelerometer, imu, gyro, mems, velocity

While reading about [IMU on wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inertial_measurement_unit) I found this about its disadvantages:

"A constant error in attitude rate (gyro) results in a quadratic error in velocity and a cubic error growth in position."

How is Gyro drift error related to error in velocity and position?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In a typical pure inertial nav solution, you must cancel out the acceleration due to gravity by subtracting it out.  If the vehicle's down vector is incorrect, this error appears as a lateral acceleration that is equal to \$\sin \theta_{error}\$ -- and for small angles is close to \$\theta_{error}\$ itself.  So if the gyro has an offset, \$\theta_{error}\$ grows linearly and therefore acceleration error grows linearly (at first).

Since velocity is the integral of acceleration, and position is the integral of velocity, a constant, linear acceleration drift (1st order polynomial) will result in a quadratic velocity error (2nd order polynomial) and cubic position error (3rd order polynomial).

If all you have is a 6-DOF IMU and a model of the earth's gravity, then both the IMU and the gravity model have to be perfect.

Answer (score 0):

Drift adds an moving offset to the angular velocity which is an error. Then if you time integrate that to get angular position the error gets transferred over and accumulates.